# How to add a number to a class name within a for loop?

Tags: for-loop

I have a number of pizzas. that number is defined by the user. the for loop will run for that length of time. each time the for loop runs I want a new class for that pizza to be made. in order to do this (as far as I know) the names need to be different. I want the default name to be "pizza" and then for each reiteration of the for loop I want it to tack on a number to pizza. i.e "pizza1" "pizza2"

using System;

namespace PizzaCalculator
{
public class Pizza
{
public double size{get;set;}
public double price{get;set;}
public double squarInch;
public double pricePerInch;
public double radius;
public double radius2;
public string brand{get;set;}

```
    public void calculate()
    {
        radius = (size/2);
        radius2 = Math.Pow(radius, 2);
        squarInch = radius2*3.14159;
        pricePerInch = Math.Round((price/squarInch),2);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {   
        double pizzaNum;


        Console.WriteLine("How many pizza's do you want to compair?");
        pizzaNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < pizzaNum; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\nPlease enter the brand of the pizza: ");
            Pizza pizza = new Pizza() {brand = Console.ReadLine()};

        }


       
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I've tried to attach [i] to the end of "pizza" but I don't really know for sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List<Pizza>`to store your pizzas.

```cpp
List<Pizza> pizzas = new List<Pizza>();

for (int i = 0; i < pizzaNum; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\nPlease enter the brand of the pizza: ");
    Pizza pizza = new Pizza() {brand = Console.ReadLine()};
    pizzas.Add(pizza);
}
```

To read the data, you can use a foreach loop:

```cpp
foreach(Pizza pizza in pizzas)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pizza.brand);
}
```

Or to access a specific pizza, you can use the indexer:

```cpp
Console.WriteLine(pizzas[0].brand);
```

Comment: If i wanted multiple variables on the pizza like "brand,size,cost" how would those be implamented into the for loop?

Comment: You can do `pizza.size` and `pizza.cost` if they are in your `pizza` object. If the require the use of getters, use `pizza.getSize()` (or whatever you named your getter).